# past or past continuous with exact time period

Tags: past-continuous

They **were playing(play)** football yesterday from 13:00 to 15:00.
 They **played(play)** football yesterday from 13:00 to 15:00.

At 8.30am today I **was driving(drive)** to work.
 At 8.30am today I **drove(drive)** to work.

We **were sleeping(sleep)** at 11pm. when he came back home.
 We **slept(sleep)** at 11pm. when he came back home.

I **was studying(study)** English at that time.
 I **studied(study)** English at that time.

Should I use past or past continuous if I mention exact time period?

Comment: You can use the *past continuous* to describe an event that was in progress at a specific time in the past: *At 7:30 this morning, I was waiting for the bus.* If we're not stating the progress of the action in the past and we mean a finished action, you use the *past simple.*

Answer (score 1):

Tip:  Be sure to use "past *continuous*," not "past continues."

Mentioning an exact time period in a sentence does not determine which verb form you should use.  It's the meaning you want your sentence to have that makes the difference.

The following site http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html uses these example...

> Last night at 6 PM, I ate dinner.
>
> Last night at 6 PM, I was eating dinner.

The first sentence means, I started eating dinner at 6 pm.  The second sentence means that I started eating earlier than 6 pm, but at 6 pm I was still in the process of eating.

Take a look at the website I gave above. It is very helpful and easy to understand.

I hope this helps!